# GetPrivateProfileString in Geotest ATEasy environment

Tags: ini, ateasy

I am trying to use the function `GetPrivateProfileString` in order to read from a `.ini` file, but for some reason, `ATEasy` does not know this function. What driver/DLL/Something else do I need to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

In order to use `GetPrivateProfileString, GetPrivateProfileInt, WritePrivateProfileString` functions, you need to add the "`Kernel32.dll`" which is located in `C:\Windows\system32\Kernel32.dll`